# How can I insert the solution of one system of differential equations into another system of differential equations using "scipy.integrate.solve_ivp"?

Tags: python, scipy, differential-equations

I am working on building the phase response curves of the van der Pol model via the adjoint method. For this it is necessary to solve the original system of differential equations and include its solutions in the adjoint system. As shown below.

The original system corresponds to:

```
def vanderpol(t, v, mu):
x, y = v
dxdt = mu*(x-(x**3)/3-y)
dydt = (1/mu)*x
return (dxdt, dydt)
```

with the parameters:

```
    mu  = 1.5
    T1  = 7.09637359
    omega1 = (2*np.pi)/T1
    tend = 25*T1
    y0  = [1, 1]
```

And the **scipy.integrate.solve_ivp** function:

```
sol = solve_ivp(vanderpol, [-tend, tend], y0, args=[mu], dense_output=True, max_step=1e-2)
```

Now, the solution function *x(t)* in the above system must be included in the following system of differential equations, which is called the adjoint system:

```
    def adjunta(t, v, mu):
    zx, zy = v
    dzxdt = -zx*(mu/omega1)*(1-x(t)**2)-zy/(mu*omega1)
    dzydt = (zx*mu)/omega1
    return (dzxdt, dzydt)
```

Where *x(t)* represents the solution function *x(t)* of the original system of differential equations.

Since that the function **sol** in **scipy.integrate.solve_ivp** returns three vectors as the result of the numerical integration *(sol.t, sol.y[0], sol.y[1])*. How can I include the *sol.y[0]* solution in the adjoint system?

Comment: Solve them simultaneously.  That is, create a higher-dimensional system whose state vector is [x, y, zx, zy].

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser It's a very elegant solution, but there is a problem. By the theory associated with the construction of the adjoint system, it is necessary to integrate backwards in time. That is, if the original system integrates on [a, b] with a greater than b, then the adjoint system must be integrated on [b, a] with a greater than b.

Comment: Use the "dense output" of `solve_ivp` as a ready-made interpolation function for the solution of the first system. // Or solve the combined system with the BVP solver.

Comment: @LutzLehmann How can I use the "dense_output" interpolation fuction? Could you show me an example? I have looked for documentation, but have not found any useful information. The idea is that you can get something of the form _x(t)_ in such a way that it can be inserted into the original system.

On the other hand, with the BVP solver can I integrate two equations in _[a, b]_ and the other two in _[b, a]_?

Answer (score 0):

If solving the two systems simultaneously is not an option, you could pass it as an argument to the adjoint system:

```py
def adjunta(t, v, mu, x):
   ...
   return (dzxdt, dzydt)
```

And you pass it through the `args` parameter in the `solve_ivp`

```py
sol = solve_ivp(adjunta, ..., args=[mu, x], ...)
```

Comment: Technically the solution _x_ offered by the function *sol* is a vector. For this reason I don't think that this is an adequate way to attack the problem since the *args* argument only receives scalars.

Comment: The `args` argument receives whatever you want to pass into `adjunta`, be it a vector, a scalar or even a function. In your case, you could even use [interp1d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html) before calling `solve_ivp` and passing a function of time in the place of `x`.